# Sign in with fb or twitter

Tags: php, facebook, api, twitter

For a project I am working on, I think having the functionality to sign in with facebook/ twitter would be beneficial.

I have some design theory to iron out.

When the user first logs into the website using either twitter or facebook, I'll get their email and other relevant information and store it in the database where a normal signed up user would be stored.

When they return, they would log in with twitter/ fb again and it would locate the information in the database and not add it again.

If anyone tried to sign up with the email address provided by either of these services, an email would be sent to the email address to confirm it is them and then they could generate just a password to allow them to log in with information already stored.

I could they link other data on the website to the userid I have stored for them throughout the entire process.

So my query would be whether this is the correct way to go about this?
How have others used these types of login api's and then binded them to on site data?

I believe this to be a reasonable question but if I have placed it in the wrong section, please feel free to move it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well, everything should be written here http://developers.facebook.com/ also try using php sdk for facebook api, for twitter here https://dev.twitter.com/

Create an app in both fb and twitter, take the access token and access token secret

You should download all the files necessary and then configure them as is written in manual, if you will have trouble connecting to them write me a message to my mail(jurijs.nesterovs@inbox.lv) i'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Have done that before myself for my site. It was Fb/Twitter/Google. I bet thats the best thing to do. Google's API is the easiest out of these 3. Twitter was hard for me since I dont use OOP and all the libraries out there was OOP.

And about your design, my site was made not to not allow the user to join with the same email again. If they have joined using Facebook with an email, when they try to join using twitter with the same email, I would tell the user that they are already registered using Facebook.